# Удалить дубликаты по условию

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В столбце `ID ученика` присутствуют дубликаты. Необходимо удалить ту строку, у которой значения столбца `Балл` **меньше**. Т.е. из данного примера необходимо удалить строки:

*1001-3*

*1003-3*

Я вижу три решения:

1. С помощью условного форматирования выделить цветом повторяющиеся строки из столбца `ID ученика`. Установить фильтр по цвету и вручную удалять строки, у которых значения столбца `Балл` **меньше**. Собственно, так я сейчас и делаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня таких строк **1000+** и как вы понимаете надо прибегнуть к другому варианту.

2. Создать VB-макрос и с помощью него удалить дубликаты согласно условию.
3. Загрузить эту таблицу в БД (к примеру, SQL Server) и с помощью разового и многоразового SQL-запроса удалить дубликаты.

Как уже упомянул выше, сейчас сижу и удаляю дубликаты по первому варианту. Есть ли у кого предложения как воспользоваться 2-ым или 3-им способом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обойтись и без макросов, и без баз данных, используя только возможности Excel:

1. Сортируете по ID ученика
2. На вкладке "Данные" нажимаете "Промежуточный итог" и выставляете операцию "Максимум".

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Сворачиваете полученные данные кликом на 2 уровне (обведен).

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Осталось скопировать. Напрямую не выйдет. Выделите ту часть, которую необходимо скопировать:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Нажимаете Ctrl+G (или идете на вкладку "Главная", в правой части - "Найти и выделить" - "Перейти"), внизу есть кнопка "Выделить...", под ней нужно выбрать "только видимые ячейки"

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Ctrl+C, в нужном месте Ctrl+V
5. Заменяем лишние надписи: Ctrl+H - найти " Максимум" (с пробелом перед словом "максимум"), заменить "". Нажимаете кнопку "Заменить все".

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаете уникальные значения с максимальной оценкой.

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите сам DELETE и подправьте имена колонок:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN 

CREATE TABLE Scores
(
    PupulID int,
    Score int
)

INSERT INTO Scores
(PupulID, Score)
VALUES
(1001, 5),
(1002, 2),
(1001, 3),
(1003, 4),
(1003, 5)

SELECT * FROM Scores

;WITH Indexed AS (SELECT PupulID, Score,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PupulID ORDER BY Score DESC) as RN
FROM SCORES)
DELETE FROM Scores 
    FROM Scores 
    INNER JOIN Indexed ON
        Scores.PupulID = Indexed.PupulID AND Scores.Score = Indexed.Score
WHERE Indexed.RN > 1

SELECT * FROM Scores

ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо всего лишь получить результат с максимальным баллом, чтобы затем вставить его в Excel, то для третьего варианта можно воспользоваться простым селектом:

```
select id_ученика, max(балл)
from таблица_с_баллами
group by id_ученика
```