# Удаление дублей из колонки с учетом содержимого в другой колонке

Tags: excel

Можно как то в google или локальном экселе:

удалять дубли по 1й колонке, но с учётом 3й ?

оставлять ток те строки - у которых самая поздняя дата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, а что именно нужно? Последовательность штатных действий или код макроса? Какие вводные? Что сделали сами?

Comment: @cauf ну по вводным я вроде всё предоставил. Я думал может функция есть какая и т.д. - тут нашёл ответы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442003/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Может, и в *Google*-таблицах так, не проверял. Вариант для *Excel*

Нужные столбцы - *A* и *C*. Первая строка - для заголовков фильтра.

В ячейку свободного столбца (в строке 2) заносим формулу:

```
=--(C2=МАКС(ЕСЛИ($A$2:$A$100=A2;$C$2:$C$100)))
```

Формула массива, требует несколько большего внимания - ввод такой формулы должен быть завершен комбинацией клавиш. Не выходя из режима редактирования формулы, жмем три клавиши - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` - формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.

Протягиваем формулу по столбцу до последней строки с данными. Строки с наибольшими датами будут отмечены единицами.

Выделяем данные и ячейки с формулой, ставим автофильтр (закладка `Данные-Фильтр`), фильтруем по доп. столбцу - оставляем единицы.

Выделяем оставшиеся данные, копируем и вставляем в другой диапазон. Победили :)